# Azure AppService crashed with no details

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My .net app hosted in Azure AppService unexpectedly crashed 4 times yesterday and I'm struggling to get details on why it went down. The report "Diagnose and solve problems\Application Crashes", indicates that Stackoverflow exceptions was the cause of the crashes, but I'm looking to get more details like (uri or stack dump). Here are the things I've tried and come up empty:

**EventLog:** I used the kudu app to get the eventLog(/api/vfs/LogFiles/eventlog.xml) and there are no details on the Stackover exceptions. In fact there are no matches on "stack", "overflow", or "recursion"

**Nlog Files:** The nlog files just abruptly terminate when these crashes occurred so no details are captured.

**Azure AppIngishts:** This too has no exceptions logged during the outage windows. There are some exceptions before and after but nothing about the details of the stack overflow.

**AppSerive Utilization:** The memory and CPU utilization were running in normal limits (40-70%) before the crashes.

[image]

Lastly, the app hasnt been updated for weeks so the likelyhood of new functionally causing this is low. In any case, I would need to know where to look as its a fairly complex app.

Any tips to disgonotise this issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could isolate the issue by running the app locally with the latest changes.

You may capture a memory dump to identify if a line in the code is causing the crash (typically array size/recursive loop). Kindly take a look at the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/06/28/capture-a-stackoverflowexception-and-make-a-dump-0xc00000fd/) for the steps.

Kindly let us know the status with more details on the issue, we would be very glad to assist you further.